# App crashes when click with empty text fields

Tags: android

I have write a method for register users for backendless. With filled all text fields I can register users. My problem is when when I click button with empty text fields app getting crash, but I wrote a if statement for check empty text fields and show a toast.

```
public void RegisterButtonPressed(View view) {

  if(email.getText() == null || password.getText() == null || username.getText() == null){

      Toast.makeText(this, "Every Fileds should be filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  } else {

      if(email.getText() != null && password.getText() != null && username.getText() != null) {

          final String emailS = email.getText().toString();
          final String passwordS = password.getText().toString();
          String usernameS = username.getText().toString();

          BackendlessUser user = new BackendlessUser();

          user.setEmail(emailS);
          user.setPassword(passwordS);
          user.setProperty("name",usernameS);
          user.setProperty("Avatar","");

          Backendless.UserService.register(user, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
              @Override
              public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser backendlessUser) {

                  Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Registration Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  Backendless.UserService.login(emailS, passwordS, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
                      @Override
                      public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser backendlessUser) {

                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

                          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Login Unsuccessfull: " + backendlessFault.getDetail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      }
                  });

              }

              @Override
              public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

                  Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Registration Unsuccesful: " + backendlessFault.getDetail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
          });

      }

  }
}
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7huz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check with

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText()))
```

instead of

```
if (email.getText() == null)
```

From my experience, the **getText()** was not return null if it empty, but empty string a.k.a ""

TextUtils.isEmpty() however, will check both null and "" as empty string

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if the string is null. If it's empty, your `if` statement will not catch that and could still cause a crash. You should be checking for empty string as well.

```
if(email.getText() == null || email.getText().length() == 0 || 
password.getText() == null || password.getText.length() == 0 || 
username.getText() == null || username.getText.length() == 0){

  Toast.makeText(this, "Every Fileds should be filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me on AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, where I have added Spinner Adapter with Filterable.

I have overrided the AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView enoughToFilter() method.

```
@Override
public boolean enoughToFilter() { 
   return showAlways || super.enoughToFilter();
}
```

**showAlways** is a bool object where I was setting apply a filter with threshold.
As **enoughToFilter ()** => Returns true if the amount of text in the field meets or exceeds the getThreshold() requirement.
On zero-length it was crashing when this **showAlways** is set to false, just make it to true or
set threshold to 0 & set **showAlways** to false.